# Getting the day of the week a year starts at

Tags: c++, date

I was making a function in C++ to get the day of the week given the day, month and year (from 1900 on). The way I have to do it (I'm following orders, it's an exercise) is with the modulus of 7 of the total of days passed.

For example, 21 November 2018 will be the 325th day of that year (Taking into account leap years). The day of the week will be 325 % 7, which will give a number between 0 and 6, 0 being Sunday, 1 being Monday and so on, until 6 which would be Saturday.

But this will only work in years that start on Monday. 2018 works, but 2019 will be off by 1 day, as it starts on Tuesday.

My idea of fixing this is by knowing on what day that year starts and adding it to the 0-6 number given (fixing it if it's higher than 6), but I'd have to use the function for the year before, which would do so until it reaches 1900, which would be set to Monday. It sounds terrible, and I can't figure out another way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "My idea of fixing this is by knowing on what day that year starts..."  isnt this what you want to compute? If you already know on what day the year starts, then what do you need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use any libraries and do it purely by calculation, here is a solution.

[http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20180829205848/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html) (Web Archive page)

or a easy explanation [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=714LTMNJy5M&t=0s&list=WL&index=82).

What you can do is convert this logic into your program and find out the day of the week.

```
int dayofweek(int d, int m, int y) 
{ 
    static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 }; 
    y -= m < 3; 
    return ( y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7; 
}
```

[Code Source.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find anything when googling this

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/

```
int weakDayOfYearBegin(int year)
{
    std::tm t {};
    t.tm_year = year - 1900;
    t.tm_mday = 1;
    std::mktime(&t);
    return t.tm_wday;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/1ZnByeurgMrEF3fA